# URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. 1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting

Tags: cakephp

I got the cakePHP and I have the following error.

URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.    1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting

The odd thing is that it is working fine on my laptop and it is not working on my desktop pc. I copy the whole thing from my laptop and paste it on the desktop and that error is shown.

Any ideas to solve? I follow the steps to solve but it is the same problem. My cakePHP version is 2.0 above.

Comment: Does url rewriting actually work? I've found that Cake sometimes mis-diagnoses this error.

Comment: yes. i copy the whole cakephp folder from my laptop and paste it on desktop. it is working fine on my laptop. Only happens on desktop.

Comment: i fixed it. thank you. i got to do the steps on the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Check first your rewrite mode is on or not in `apache/conf/httpd.conf` file.
check below code in `httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Hash remove in this line and restart Apache server:

```
#sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that you can set below code in your cakephp `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /YourPath/
    RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/      [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*)  app/webroot/$1    [L]       
 </IfModule>
```